# How to call webservice in HTML page using JQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, ajax, web-services

i have WebService that get 2 string and return if they equals

***WebService that in http://192.168.100.MyIP/HTML_SIMPLE_TEST/***

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
     [WebMethod(Description = "Validate the login credentials")]
     public bool Validate(string UserName, string Password)
     {
          if (Password == "test" && UserName == "test")
              return true;
          else
              return false;
     }
}
```

and i have html page that call this WebService and need to return the Result

```
<html  lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        var Surl = "http://localhost:3031/WS_HTML/Service1.asmx/Validate";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input#submit").click(function (event) {
                //var uid = document.getElementById("UserName").value;
                //var pwd = document.getElementById("Password").value;

                var uid = "test";
                var pwd = "test";

                var dataString = "{ 'UserName' : '" + uid + "', 'Password' : '" + pwd + "'}";

                $.ajax({
                    ServiceCallID: 1,
                    url: Surl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataString,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (result) {
                        returnVal = result.d;
                        alert(returnVal);
                    },

                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        returnVal = '';
                    }
                });
            });
        });

</script>

</head>
    <body >
        <form method=post runat="server">
            <input  type="submit" />Connet to my WS
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this what i get:
[image]

and i try this, still same problem....

```
<script>
    function XX() {
        alert("in");
        $.post('http://localhost/WS_HTML/Service1.asmx/Validate', { username: 'test', password: 'test' }, function (response) {
            response; // Here is response
            alert(response);
        });
    }
</script>

</head>
    <body >
         <form method=post runat="server">
            <input  type="submit" onclick="XX();" />Connet to my WS2
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i try with `$.get` - and same.... Nothing happens....

from the browser its work. if i write this: `localhost/WS_HTML/Service1.asmx` i see my WS,

but if i write this: `localhost/WS_HTML/Service1.asmx/Validate` i see error on browser =>

**Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/Validate'.**

I swear to God that for several days I break my head and can not figure out why it does not work

):

thanks,

Comment: What is "ServiceCallID: 1," for?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem... "it does not work" is not really a valid problem description. Is the request made, does it return something, ect. ect.

Comment: Looks like you cannot call the web service method using "POST"? Have you tried accessing the web service page through the browser? does it work?

Comment: yes, through he browser its works excellent

Answer (score 0):

You not forced to use jQuery for make Ajax request. You can use standard javascript (it's more efficient, and you have not to load library for that...)

Also, you don't have to create an `click event` for submit your form, you can juste create an HTML structure and submit by an `onclick` attribute, is more efficient (less browser memory).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myUrl = "http://localhost:3031/WS_HTML/Service1.asmx/Validate";

            function submitMyForm(){
                // Define your datas 
                var uid = "test";
                var pwd = "test";
                var dataString = "{ 'UserName' : '" + uid + "', 'Password' : '" + pwd + "'}";

                // Create and send the request
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    // Log with console.log() or alert if you want...
                    console.log('State of my request changed! ');
                    if (XMLHttpRequest.DONE === request.readyState) {
                        console.log(request.responseText);
                    }
                }
                request.open('POST', myUrl, true);
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                request.send(data);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <button onclick="submitMyForm()" >Connect to my WS</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see you use a basic javascript `alert()` on your code, for the debug you can use `console.log()` (you can see the doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Console/log)).

For your question, I don't think the problem is your HTML/Javascript. jQuery method you've look right. HTML too.

I think you've a problem with your server, This not a client problem. It's a server error : you can see that with your HTTP status code (405 -> doumentation for this HTTP code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)).

Have you right configured your server ? You can surrely found informations about `405 method not Allowed - ISS server` on this website, on or the [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=en-US)

Hope I help you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use $.post() ?

```
$.post('/your/service/url/', {username:'asd', password:'qwe'}, function(response){
    response; // Here is response
});
```

Comment: Error which showed at top says "Method not allowed". Maybe you just forget to allow POST method? For example, try use $.get instead of $.post

Comment: i try with $.get - and same.... Nothing happens.... from the browser its work. if i write this: http://localhost/WS_HTML/Service1.asmx  i see my WS, but if i write this: 
http://localhost/WS_HTML/Service1.asmx/Validate i see error on browser => Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/Validate'.